# How to include .js in html from wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

For the life of me I cannot see why this is giving me so much trouble. Here is the setup:

```
/src/js/myscript.js
/src/views/mypage.html
myplugin.php
```

Inside of myplugin.php I am doing an include('src/views/mypage.html') which mostly works.. However inside of mypage.html I am trying to include the myscript.js file. The .js file fails to load. I have tried to link to it in every way that I can think of, but no luck. Surely this is a simple fix, can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: This depends on where the root of your webserver is located at. Is it at the level of myplugin.php a <script src="/src/js/myscript.js"></script> should work. But without further information its difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: use the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function.

This is a variation of an [old question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556).

But, as of WordPress 6.3, a new `$args` parameter has been added to `wp_enqueue_script`. Also, there is now a lot of good documentation available on developer.wordpress.org. So, I have provided those links in the answer below.

Directly from [WordPress plugin documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#enqueue):

> You cannot enqueue scripts directly from your plugin code page when it is loaded. Scripts must be enqueued from one of a few action hooks – which one depends on what sort of page the script needs to be linked to. For administration pages, use admin_enqueue_scripts. For front-end pages use wp_enqueue_scripts, except for the login page, in which case use login_enqueue_scripts.

### `wp_enqueue_script`

Use the `wp_enqueue_script` function to add JavaScript (for the front-end) from a plugin. Please read the [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) carefully on its use. The docs say: *The function should be called using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook [...] Calling it outside of an action hook can lead to problems*.

The code example below was adapted from a comment on the WordPress documentation page.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', array() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

### To summarize:

Your HTML file needs to be updated to remove the `<script>` tag, and the JavaScript file needs to be enqueued with the `wp_enqueue_script` function. Pay attention to the loading strategy. It is based on whether your script should execute immediately upon loading, or after the DOM tree has fully loaded.

More details are available on [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript).

## Update

Below, is a complete example demonstrating use of `wp_enqueue_script` for a shortcode.

The shortcode tag in the example is: `your-shortcode-tag`

### `<plugin root>`/src/views/mypage.html

```
<div id="my-fabulous-div">Hello World!</div>
```

### `<plugin root>`/src/js/myscript.js

```
let greeting = document.createElement( 'span' );
greeting.textContent = ' nice to meet you.';
let divElement = document.getElementById( 'my-fabulous-div' );
divElement.append( greeting );
```

### `<plugin root>`/myplugin.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       MyPlugIn
 * Description:       Some description.
 * Requires at least: 6.3
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Author:            Your Name
 * License:           The license
 * License URI:       The license URL
 * Text Domain:       myplugin
 */

add_action( 'init', array( 'MyPlugin_Shortcode_Class', 'init' ) );


/**
 * MyPlugin Shortcode Class
 *
 */
class MyPlugin_Shortcode_Class {

    /**
     * Class constructor. Noop.
     */
    public function __construct() {}


    /**
     * Initialize stuff.
     */
    public static function init() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MyPlugin_Shortcode_Class::enqueue_scripts', 10, 1 );
        add_shortcode( 'your-shortcode-tag', 'MyPlugin_Shortcode_Class::render_shortcode', 10, 1 );
    }


    /**
     * Enqueue JavaScript.
     */
    public static function enqueue_scripts() {
        global $post;

        // Enclosing wp_enqueue_script with an if-statement is optional. Update the conditions
        // as required (e.g. you might want to test for a specific custom post type).
        // Note that calling has_shortcode() negatively affects performance.
        if ( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'your-shortcode-tag') ) {
            wp_enqueue_script(
                'your-script-handle',
                plugins_url( 'src/js/myscript.js', __FILE__ ),
                array(), // Dependencies. List of other script handles.
                false,   // Default. Adds currently installed WordPress version to query string.
                array( 'strategy' => 'defer', 'in_footer' => true )  // Script loading strategies.
            );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Return shortcode HTML to WordPress for rendering.
     *
     * @param array  $attrs         Shortcode attributes.
     * @param string $content       Content between shortcode opening and closing tags.
     * @param string $shortcode_tag Shortcode tag.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function render_shortcode( $attrs, $content, $shortcode_tag ) {
        $html_filepath = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'src/views/mypage.html';
        $html = file_get_contents( $html_filepath );
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I am very grateful for your answer and you taking the time to help me! Am I missing a "bigger picture" here? Why is outputting a simple HTML file with .js linked such an ordeal? So I made a basic plugin to display my page. I created a WP page, create and use a shortcode to get anything on that page. Now I have to go and research an entirely new function/hook and figure that out. So I will need to convert the .html page into a .php script, then remove the ```<script>``` tag and replace it with some php code that has that function you showed in example?

Comment: Part of the bigger picture is security. Sending JavaScript to the browser opens the door to security threats that are reduced by using `wp_enqueue_script`. This [Website Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Website_security) page on mozilla.org offers a comprehensive listing of website security threats from these links: 1. [Web security exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Web_security_exploits); 2. [Open Web Application Security Project](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/).

Comment: *So I will need to convert the .html page into a .php script*. Not really. You can still grab the HTML file and use it in your shortcode's return value. *...then remove the <script> tag*: Yes, you must remove the `<script>` tag. *...and replace it with some php code that has that function you showed in example?*: The example code is not meant to be copied directly into your code as a direct replacement. I have updated my answer with a complete example demonstrating how to add JavaScript for a shortcode.